# Gem devise set multiple user model system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, admin

In my app i need to do two way-login system:
1) User - only for user part of website, contain's information about user's, it's login data, etc...
2) Admin - another model for admin part of website.

But how to do this? 
Now i have only first part, and my migration:

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table(:users) do |t|
     ## Database authenticatable
     t.string :email, :null => false, :default => ""
     t.string :encrypted_password, :null => false, :default => ""

     ## Recoverable
     t.string :reset_password_token
     t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

     ## Rememberable
     t.datetime :remember_created_at

     ## Trackable
     t.integer :sign_in_count, :default => 0
     t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
     t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
     t.string :current_sign_in_ip
     t.string :last_sign_in_ip

     ## Encryptable
     # t.string :password_salt

     ## Confirmable
     #t.string :confirmation_token
     #t.datetime :confirmed_at
     #t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
     #t.string :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

     ## Lockable
     #t.integer :failed_attempts, :default => 0 # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
     #t.string :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
     #t.datetime :locked_at

     ## Token authenticatable
     t.string :authentication_token

     t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :users, :email, :unique => true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, :unique => true
    #add_index :users, :confirmation_token, :unique => true
    #add_index :users, :unlock_token, :unique => true
    add_index :users, :authentication_token, :unique => true
   end

  def self.down
    drop_table :users
  end
end
```

And route:

```
devise_for :users
```

But how to add second admin-login part?

Comment: Someone wise enough to read [docs](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-multiple-models). And also don't be so rude if you want to get help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 options:

1. Add string field `type` to your table and derive from `User` model (the admin and user will have the same login route).
2. Add boolean field `admin` and use i.e. CanCan gem.
3. Run `rails g devise admin` and have separate admin model.

The way you choose depends on your app struct.